# Is it possible to build a system to continuously listen for message using azure bus services?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, message-queue

I am trying to create a logger module using NodeJs and Azure bus services, which should be capable of listening for messages from the queue and process it based on business logic.

I tried it using Topics and subscription under standard tier in azure bus services, but couldn't make it listen continuously.

Comment: *but couldn't make it listen continuously* what exactly do you mean by that, did you write some code and if so, how and where did you run it?

Comment: I have written a function to query the messages in the queue, so whenever I call that function it will return message. Whereas, I need a system like Pub/Sub to return the message once it is posted in the subscribed queue/topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) meets your needs. Azure Functions supports trigger and output bindings for Service Bus queues and topics.

You could use the Service Bus trigger to listen for and respond to messages from a Service Bus queue or topic.

Further more information you could refer to this doc:[Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

Comment: Is there a way to build the Pub/Sub model using azure function and azure service bus?

Comment: There is a blog about processing service message via the pub-sub pattern, may be this is what you want.https://www.simongilbert.net/serverless-azure-functions-service-bus-table-storage/